# awk to add single quotes around particular column and concat with other column

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

how to add single quotes to particular column in a file and concat with other which is in a same file.

Example: file1.txt has some 10 columns, add single quotes to $6 column and concat with $9 column.

I have tried: `awk -F '|' '{print $6 ":" $9 }' file1.csv`

Comment: You will get better, and more useful, answers if you show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I tried this below for which i want to add single quotes around $6 i.e 6th column    Example:   awk -F '|' '{print $6 ":" $9  }' file1.csv

Comment: awk -F '|' '{print $6 ":" $9 }' file1.csv

Comment: It is not clear where you want the single quotes to be added.  Show some sample input and your corresponding desired output.

Comment: Either set a variable to a single quote using -v or use \047 as octal version in print

Comment: So presumably `1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9` will become `’6’9` ?

Comment: Yes Mark that's right, need solution plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | awk -F'|' '{print "\047" $6 "\047" $9}'
'6'9
```

Or, with a variable `q` to hold the quote:

```
echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | awk -F'|' '{q="\047"; print q $6 q $9}'
```

Or, if you prefer hex:

```
echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | awk -F'|' '{q="\x27"; print q $6 q $9}'
```

Or, you could pass the quote in as a variable:

```
echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | awk -F'|' -v q="'" '{print q $6 q $9}'
```

Or, slightly shorter:

```
echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9" | awk -F'|' -v q=\' '{print q $6 q $9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed too

```
echo "..." | sed -E "s/([^\|]*\|){5}([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*\|){2}([^\|]*).*/'\2'\4/"
```

If field 9 is always the last

```
echo "..." | sed -E "s/([^\|]*\|){5}([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*\|){2}(.*)/'\2'\4/"
```